# Whishes if only and will

Tags: grammar, verbs

Which one is correct:
a. I wish that man stopped making so much noise
or
b. I wish that man will stop making so much noise?

Comment: Neither. c. I wish that man would stop making so much noise.

Answer (score 2):

Both are grammatical, but uncommon. The normal form is

> I wish that man would stop making so much noise.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as Colin said, both are grammatical, however they also change the tense of the statement.

"I wish that man stopped making so much noise" is more akin to "I wish that man had stopped making so much noise" as if you are talking about a recently passed event.

"I wish that man will stop making so much noise" is a bit of a future tense, and is comprehensible, but sounds clumsy.

Colin's answer is succinct, though I would maybe even go further and say "I wish he'd stop making so much noise," or better yet "I wish he'd quiet down."

I'm a fan of cutting word count, though.